# Free, easy tty calling app for the deaf and lazy

Tags: phone

Looking for a free and easy way to call automated 1-800 numbers without needing to speak. Right now, it's a pain to call because I'd be waking a roommate. There are a million scenarios where speaking is very inconvenient, at work, while socializing, while riding a train bus or plane, and if you are literally not capable.

I would like to be able to type instead of speak. I'm on Mac OS but would prefer a web app.

Comment: What OS(es) do you need support for?

Comment: Would you use headphones? Or should it be automatic, for instance the software recognizes what is being said, and generate speech when asked a particular question? I think you should split into two questions: One with headphones, and one totally automatic. As said by Nick, we can't help you if you don't tell us whether you want an app for Android or Linux or something else. Also tell us your budget.

Comment: I don't have a budget, if I was really set on getting ahold of this I would be writing it myself, I just wanted to get the idea out there. It would be cool to see it as a google hangouts app/addon, I doubt this is possible through their api, but maybe some extra javascript could make it happen (bookmarklet, extension, etc)

Comment: So I guess I'm primarily focused on desktop. The full keyboard gives you an acceptable typing/reply speed.